# Prevent Parallels Desktop from recognizing external monitor

Tags: macos, mac, multiple-monitors, parallels

I use Parallels Desktop (running Windows 10) and have an external monitor, but I *dont* want Parallels/Windows to detect/extend to said monitor automatically. I like having my Mac on one monitor and Windows on the other, and I can easily accomplish this by going to Display Settings in Windows and, under Multiple Displays, changing from "Extend these displays" to "Show only on 1".

However, I am constantly moving throughout the day and connecting/disconnecting from the external monitor, and, every time I reconnect, Windows automatically detects the external and changes the display settings back to "Extend these displays".

How can I prevent this from happening? Exploring preferences for Parallels didn't come up with anything useful (although I may have overlooked it).

Running Parallels Desktop 12 on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6.

Comment: I earned the tumbleweed badge for this question... lol. Lonely souls who make it to this page, know that I too pondered the same query.

Answer (score 2):

I have Parallels 10:
- when the VM is open, in the Parallels Menu->View I see "Use all displays in Full Screen" perhaps you can use this.
- also there is a menu point Devices->External Devices->Configure.